# How do I get `tr` command to ignore newline?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I want to replace multiple spaces by a single space. I am using `tr` to do this. But it is also replacing new line with a space. How can I avoid it?

Code:

```
tr -s [:space:] ' '
```

Input:

```
He  llo
Wor  ld
how  are  you
```

Required Output:

```
He llo
Wor ld
how are you
```

My Output:

```
He llo Wor ld how are you
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:space:` matches both horizontal and vertical white space. Use `:blank:` instead to match horizontal whitespace only.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `tr -s [:space:]` without `' '` at the end to squeeze the consecutive whitespaces into one.

or you can use one of these commands:

With **tr** command:

```
tr -s ' '         < input.txt > output.txt
tr -s '[:blank:]' < input.txt > output.txt
tr -s \           < input.txt > output.txt
```

With **sed** command:

```
sed 's/  */ /g'             < input.txt > output.txt
sed 's/ \{1,\}/ /g'         < input.txt > output.txt
sed -E 's/ +/ /g'           < input.txt > output.txt
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/ /g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

with **awk** command:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' < input.txt > output.txt
awk '$1=$1""'  < input.txt > output.txt
```